# Restrict osCommerce Shopping Cart To Only Allow 1 Item For All Special Items(discounted items)

Tags: oscommerce

I don't want customers to add more than one unique item in their basket(For All Special Items[Discounted Items] in osCommerce. I know that for the same product the multiple count can be restricted by setting:

Admin → Configuration → Maximum values → Product Quantities In Shopping Cart = 1, but I want to add option for Special Items[Discounted Items], the same with this one but for Special items.

Answer (score 0):

Try somethning like this in shopping_cart.php

```
 $products = $cart->get_products();

    for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($products); $i<$n; $i++) {

        $nb_specials=0;
        if (tep_get_products_special_price((int)$products[$i]['id'])!='') {
                        $nb_specials++;
                        if($nb_specials>=2){
                            $cart->remove($products[$i]['id']);
                            echo '<span class="messageStackSuccess">Only 1 special product please</span>';
                        }

        }

}
```